# Batch file for PuTTY/PSFTP file transfer automation

Tags: batch-file, cmd, sftp, putty, psftp

I have a batch file for moving file from my local PC to server through SFTP. I have PuTTY installed in my system and the batch file code follows.

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY
psftp
open <IP>
<user>
<PW>
cd /home/irisuser/iris/integration/dls_dlsblr_dlschnn_in_msg/in
lcd d:\
put log.sh
bye
```

The above code perfectly works when I type it in command prompt. But when I double click the `.bat` file and run it, it's not running and asking for username and password to be entered. My aim was to automate the whole thing and I need to run it by simply clicking the `.bat` file. But am not able to achieve it. Any ideas or snippets will help me.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need to store the psftp script (lines from `open` to `bye`) into a separate file and pass that to `psftp` using `-b` switch:

```
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY"
psftp -b "C:\path\to\script\script.txt"
```

Reference:
[https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter6.html#psftp-option-b](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter6.html#psftp-option-b)

---

EDIT: For username+password: As you cannot use `psftp` commands in a batch file, for the same reason, you cannot specify the username and the password as `psftp` commands. These are inputs to the `open` command. While you can specify the username with the `open` command (`open <user>@<IP>`), you cannot specify the password this way. This can be done on a `psftp` command line only. Then it's probably cleaner to do all on the command-line:

```
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY"
psftp -b script.txt <user>@<IP> -pw <PW>
```

And remove the `open`, `<user>` and `<PW>` lines from your `script.txt`.

Reference:
[https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter6.html#psftp-starting](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter6.html#psftp-starting)
[https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-cmdline-pw](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-cmdline-pw)

---

What you are doing atm is that you run `psftp` without any parameter or commands. Once you exit it (like by typing `bye`), your batch file continues trying to run `open` command (and others), what Windows shell obviously does not understand.

---

If you really want to keep everything in one file (the batch file), you can write commands to psftp standard input, like:

```
(
    echo cd ...
    echo lcd ...
    echo put log.sh
) | psftp <user>@<IP> -pw <PW>
```

Though this has side effects. For example, if the host is not known to plink (like if you run it first time on a new machine or under another local account, for example under Task Scheduler), the first line of input will be taken as a response to the host key prompt. Anything except for `y`/`i`/`Enter` is interpreted as as `n` (connect just once, without adding the key to the cache), so even the `cd` command. And the rest of the script will fail as the `cd` does not happen.

Answer (score 0):

```
set DSKTOPDIR="D:\test"
set IPADDRESS="23.23.3.23"

>%DSKTOPDIR%\script.ftp ECHO cd %PAY_REP%
>>%DSKTOPDIR%\script.ftp ECHO mget *.report
>>%DSKTOPDIR%\script.ftp ECHO bye

:: run PSFTP Commands
psftp <domain>@%IPADDRESS% -b %DSKTOPDIR%\script.ftp
```

Set values using set commands before above lines.

I believe this helps you.

Referre psfpt setup for below link https://www.ssh.com/ssh/putty/putty-manuals/0.68/Chapter6.html