# Encountering erros when trying to automate PSFTP command using a .bat file

Tags: batch-file, putty

In looking at other posts, "[Batch file for PuTTY/PSFTP file transfer automation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16439039/batch-file-for-putty-file-transfer-automation)", regarding automating the PSFTP command in a .bat file so that I can setup a Windows Scheduled Task, I tried the following but got the error below:

In the .bat file that I'm executing I have the following lines:

```
@echo off
cd "c:\PuTTY"
psftp 999.99.999.999 -l XXXXXIO -i testGSX.ppk -b DownloadDiscoverReports.txt
```

In the DownloadDiscoverReports.txt file I have the following lines:

```
lcd c:\Reports\GSXDLFILES\ALLRPTS
cd /DSCVROUT/ALLRPTS/
mget *ALLRPTS%POLLABLE*
lcd c:\Reports\GSXDLFILES\XMIT81
cd /DSCVROUT/XMIT81/
mget *XMIT81%POLLABLE*
```

The error I'm getting when I execute the .bat file from my C:\ is:

```
C:\>gsx_dl.bat
psftp: no hostname specified; use "open host.name" to connect
New local directory is c:\Reports\GSXDLFILES\ALLRPTS
psftp: not connected to a host; use "open host.name"

C:\PuTTY>
```

Any suggestions/direction on how to fix this issue would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Since I did not get a response I'd like to try and clarify.  When I execute the commands in my .bat file from the command line at my c:\PuTTY prompt it works great.  But when I try to execute the .bat file from my c:\ I get the same error I did above. Again, any help/direction would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

This issue has been resolved.  PuTTY support responded to my issue and I entered a -v switch to my command and found that my KEY had expired and that was the issue.

Thanks anyway.