# Using PSFTP to send file to remote server

Tags: batch-file, putty, psftp

I have a bat file I call everynight to transfer some files.

I want to put a file from my computer to my remote server. I have installed PSFTP and I don't know how to use it in batch way.

I put this :

```
CD /D C:\Users\Vincent\Desktop
psftp user@99.99.99.99 -pw password -P port
put file.csv /remote/folder/file.csv
```

But when I call my BAT file, it stucks on :

```
psftp > _
```

How can I use it as automate mode ?

Comment: You need to use the `-b` switch of `psftp` and to provide a text file containing the `put` command line; the way you are doing it right now lets `put` be interpreted as a `cmd` (Windows command prompt) command...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a file which contains the commands you wish to run. In this case

```
put file.csv /remote/folder/file.csv
```

Then pass that file with the -b option to PSFTP.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/16440468/6550457 for an example.

using PSFTP as you have will open it in interactive mode which is why you get the prompt. The -b will run it in batch mode.

Comment: Ok works ! I wanted to use a one-file solution but it's ok. Thanks.

Comment: You can echo the commands to a temporary file and then use that if you want a single file solution.