# How to open a session in PuTTY and execute a command without using a file containing the command?

Tags: putty

I know that you can open a PuTTY session and execute a command using a file containing the command, but I was wondering, is there a way to just run the command without the inserting it in a file?

Thanks,

Comment: Not sure but this post might help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16439039/batch-file-for-putty-psftp-file-transfer-automation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not with PuTTY. But for automation, you should not use PuTTY anyway. That's a GUI application for an interactive use.

For automation, use [Plink (PuTTY command-line connection tool)](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter7.html). The Plink supports the same set of command-line arguments as PuTTY, but can also accept a command on its command line:

```
plink -ssh user@example.com command
```