# PowerShell scripts just hangs without moving to next statement when trying to run psftp commands

Tags: powershell, sftp, powershell-5.1, psftp

I have a following PowerShell scripts which is to get a file from remote Linux server to local directory, using `psftp` and `get` commands. These two commands as standalone, works just fine. However, as a following script `copy.ps1`:

```
psftp myusername@linux-host
get /tmp/file1 D:\folder\file1.dat
quit
```

I get following output:

```
C:\Users\myusername\Desktop\copy.ps1
psftp : Using username "myusername".
At C:\Users\myusername\Desktop\copy.ps1:1 char:1
+ psftp myusername@linux-host
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Using username "myusername".:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
 
Pre-authentication banner message from server:
| Authorized uses only. All activity may be monitored and reported.
End of banner message from server
Remote working directory is /home/myusername
```

So, there are two issues:

First `NativeCommandError` and then after the output `Remote working directory` the shell just stays there without moving ahead with `get` command. I must do `^C` to bring the terminal back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are combining `psftp` commands and PowerShell commands (in your case just the `psftp` invocation) into one file. That cannot work. PowerShell stops on the call to the `psftp` and waits for it to finish. `psftp` on the contrary does not know that the PowerShell script even exist, so it cannot read its commands from there.

Put your `psftp` commands (lines `open` though `quit`) into a separate file (`download.txt`) and execute it with the following command:

```
"C:\Program Files\PuTTY\psftp.exe -b c:\path\to\download.txt
```

Alternatively, you can feed the commands to `psftp` standard input.

A related question:
[Batch file for PuTTY/PSFTP file transfer automation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16439039/850848)